# Confused about the use of arctan and the presence of 180.

Tags: trigonometry

In my high school math class I'm currently working on solving trigonometric equations.

Solve for all possible values of x:

$5 = 30\cos(2x + 1) - 5 $

My teacher (on some examples posted online) achieved this result.

$x = \frac{\arctan(\frac{1}{3}) \pm 180 + 1}{2}$

My question is: Why is arctan being used? Is there a relationship between arctan and cos that I'm missing? Why isn't arccos being used instead?

Also the plus-minus 180. I think it has something to do with the range of the cos function but I'm not exactly sure either.

Sorry for any formatting issues, first time poster.

Comment: You are right to have doubt, the answer is completely wrong ! It should be $2x+1=\arccos(1/3)+2k\pi$ or $2x+1=-\arccos(1/3)+2k\pi$. Therefore, $x=...$

Comment: Hi, I'm still slightly confused about your answer, but this helps clarify the arctan and the arccos confusion I had :). What is the correct solution for x in degrees?

Comment: $x$ is in radian. The conversion in degree shouldn't be that difficult...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have:
$$5=30\cos(2x+1)-5$$
$$\to \frac 13 =\cos(2x+1)$$
$$\to 2x+1 =\arccos(\frac 13)$$
$$\to x=\frac12(\arccos(\frac13)-1)$$

Now, notice that:
$$\cos(x)=\cos(x+360)=\cos(x-360)=\cos(x+720)=...$$

Because $\cos(x)$ is a periodic function with period $360^0$

Because of this, $$\arccos(\frac 13)=I\pm360k$$

Also, because $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$, we have $-\arccos(\frac 13)$ fittingas well.

For any integer $k$, where  $I\approx70.527$ is the initial value of $\arccos(\frac13)$

That's why the $\pm 180$ bit came in to the solution, even if it's slightly off.

Comment: You're missing -arccos(1/3).

Comment: That's very true, thank you